# postgresql ALL subquery evaluates empty to true

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a `WHERE` clause condition that involves an `ALL` subquery.  Sometimes the subquery result is empty in which case the expression always evaluates to `true`, but I want it to evaluate to `false`.

For example, suppose I have a table of drivers, a table of routes, and a many-to-many interaction table showing which routes each driver has driven. I want to find drivers who have only driven routes further than 50 miles.

```
SELECT * FROM driver 
WHERE 50 < ALL(
    SELECT miles FROM route, driver_route
    WHERE driver_route.route_id = route.id AND
          driver_route.driver_id = driver.id)
```

This query will include drivers who haven't driven any routes in the results, which is not what I want.

I've tried using coalesce, but ran into `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.  Here's how I phrased that query:

```
SELECT * FROM driver 
WHERE 50 < COALESCE((
    SELECT ALL(SELECT miles FROM route, driver_route 
    WHERE driver_route.route_id = route.id AND 
          driver_route.driver_id = driver.id)), 
    0);
```

I'm looking for a structure that's general enough to be applied to different types and queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this

```
SELECT * FROM driver  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
    SELECT miles FROM route, driver_route  
    WHERE driver_route.route_id = route.id AND  
          driver_route.driver_id = driver.id AND   
          miles <= 50  
                 )  
 AND EXISTS (  
    SELECT miles FROM route, driver_route  
    WHERE driver_route.route_id = route.id AND  
          driver_route.driver_id = driver.id AND  
          miles > 50  
                 )
```

All being greater than 50 is equivalent to none being smaller or equal to 50.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The result is the same.  If I understand exists correctly, this query explicitly includes empty results, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @user3747260 adapted with `AND EXISTS` to require at least one `miles > 50`.

Comment: hah, of course.  Despite the duplication the query planner seems to handle this well.  I have to say I'm surprised this isn't a common problem and there isn't a more standard solution, but yours seems to work well.  Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to post another question with the really complicated stuff later on, then :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
select driver.* from driver inner join (
    select driver.id  from driver
    inner join driver_route 
    on driver.id = driver_route.driver_id
    inner join route
    on route.id = driver_route.route_id
    group by driver.id 
    having min(route.miles) > 50
)t 
on driver.id = t.id
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and it works.  Unfortunately I'm looking for a general solution with the same structure that can be applied to different types and the use of min complicates things quite a bit.